For what $t$ does $t$-convexity imply $\frac{1}{2}$-convexity?
Let's call a real-real function $f$ $t$-convex if $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. My question is for what values of $t$ does $t$-convexity imply $\frac{1}{2}$-convexity. Now obviously it holds for $t\in [0,1]$, but are there any other values?

I don't understand; are you saying that for any $t\in [0,1]$, $t$-convexity implies $\frac12$-convexity? Any function is $1$-convex.

$t\in(0,1)$ is clearly necessary for the desired implication because $x\mapsto -x^2$ is $t$-convex for any $t\le 0$ (as well as for $t\ge 1$),

Note that $t$-convex implies $(1-t)$-convex. Also, $t$- and $u$-convex implies $tu$-convex. Let $A\subset \mathbb Z[X]$ be the smallest set of polynomials such that $X\in A$, and $P(X)\in A$ implies $1-P(X)\in A$, and $P(X),Q(X)\in A$ implies $P(X)Q(X)\in A$. Now every $t$ such that $P(t)=\frac12$ for some $P\in A$, has the desired implication. The set of such $t$ is only countable, but readily seen to be dense in $(0,1)$. Without assuming something like continuity of $f$, I am not sure if more can be said.

Why would $0$-convex imply anything?

@HagenvonEitzen The problem doesn't seem to assume continuity. Thanks anyway.
